# How to pre-populate input field using Redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I've been reading the Redux Form [documentation](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/initializefromstate/) about prepopulating a form with a set of initial values, however in the example on that page the values are fetched at the click of a button, while I need to have them right away when the page loads.

Below is what I have so far. I can receive the initial values as props in the render() method just fine, but then I'm not sure what to do to pass those values to the Field component...

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'; 
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'; 

import requireAuth from '../components/hocs/requireAuth'; 

import { updateUserInfo } from '../actions/userActions'; 

class UserProfilePage extends React.Component { 

    renderField( field ) {
        return(
            <div className="input-wrap">
                <label htmlFor={ field.name }>{ field.label }</label>
                <input type="text" { ...field.input } />
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {

        console.log( 'Initial values', this.props.initialValues );

        // Here's what this.props.initialValues looks like: 
        // {
        //    first_name: 'John',
        //    last_name: 'Doe'
        // } 

        return (
            <form>
                <Field
                    label="Your first name"
                    name="first_name"
                    component={ this.renderField } />
            </form>
        );
    }

}

UserProfilePage = connect( 
    state => ({
        initialValues: state.currentUser.personal_info
    })
)( UserProfilePage ); 

UserProfilePage = reduxForm({
    form: 'UpdateProfileForm'
})( UserProfilePage );

export default requireAuth( UserProfilePage );
```

Comment: Use initialValues props.

https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-initialvalues-object-lt-string-string-gt-code-optional-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you are going to render UserProfilePage there pass it as prop such as:

```
import UserProfilePage form 'path/to/UserProfilePage';
<UserProfilePage
  {...otherProps}
  initialValues={{first_name: user.first_name}}
/>
```

And this way when the form renders the input with name as first_name will have the passed value